# How to destory ZFS "phantom" pool after re-installing zfs pool

Tags: zfs

Have a couple new disks I was setting up in ZFS mirror mode (using [Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS). Sadly I messed up something (during the grub installation) and had to start over. When I rebooted (step 6.5 in that doc) i got an error:

```
cannot import 'rpool': more than one matching pool
import by numeric ID instead
```

and it punted me into the initramfs shell. There are, indeed two rpools but one of them is broken... presumably the one from the original install. I was able to import the "good" rpool using it's ID as rpoolgood and re-exported it.

I am, however unable to import the "broken" rpool (either by name or ID). All I want to do is destroy it. My guess is I should have zeroed out the non-data partitions before creating the new partitions (step 2.2). I've got no real data on there yet so I can (and probably should) just go through the install again (and ZERO out the partitions first).

Before doing the re-install, i'm curious if there's a way to blast that bad/bogus rpool.

Per request, I am attaching a screenshot of a "zfs import" after re-exporting rpoolgood. IIRC, I had accidentally specified a partition rather than the disk when doing my grub install.. i had only done it on one of the disks when I realized my error.

[image]

Comment: I assume the "bad" pool was using the same physical devices? Does the command: _zpool import -D_ list any destroyed pools?

Comment: Running zdb to see if anything looks odd with your zpool.cache file might (or might not) give some insight into the problem. If anything seems at all amiss it should be safe to delete /etc/zfs/zpool.cache then run _zpool set cachefile=/etc/zfs/zpool.cache <pool>_  to create a new one. Though I think this is worth doing, I don't think it is the final solution.

Comment: import -D didn't show any destroyed ones (and not surprising since the reinstallation was done outside the purview of the zfs toolset). I tried a couple queries with zdb and it didn't give me any more insight (but that's probably got more to do with my lack of experience with zfs). BTW i'm using  zfs for my root filesystem so /etc/zfs/... feels like a chicken-and-egg thing at best... at worst non-sequitur since /etc/ does not exist until rpool is imported.

Comment: I think I have a simple(?) solution, but one more piece of information would be helpful.  What is the output of _zpool import_, with no pool names, and let me know if the good rpool was imported or not when you ran the command.

Comment: Attached a screen capture per your request. Thanks for any thoughts airhuff.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I found a script on a FreeBSD forum that I thought would work but it failed me.  It ran like everything was working but it changed nothing.  You might [try it](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/26282/) though as you have nothing to loose.  Let me know if you try it.

Comment: I've seen a couple scripts involving clearing of labels but none of the posts I've seen have filled me with confidence that the metadata will be left in a good state. Since I've not gone through installing the rest of the system, I think i'm going to start from "scratch" and zero out the first and last 10MB on the two drives and go from there. That should blast the metadata/partition info from what I've read.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help, good luck.  I would be sure to run _zpool labelclear_ at some point.

Comment: I've heard comments to the effect that, since the disk was re-used, label clear would not help

Comment: Probably not by itself, but it definitely won't hurt.  I just meant to do it in conjunction with your (good) idea of zeroing out the drives in the way you described. It's just so simple and harmless in your case I'd just do it, maybe before zeroing to see what if anything happens (see if the output of_zpool import_ or _zdb_ changes), or if zeroing out fails you then try it in hopeless desperation. Bottom line: low probability of success, but "free" (quick, simple and harmless in your situation) to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorta solved:

TL/DR: I deleted all partitions then blasted the first and last 10MB of each disk using dd (for an elegant way to blast the final section of a disk use [this exchange article][1]). This didn't recover the 'good' pool but that was not imperative for me... getting a clean install was the primary goal (which this gave me)

Slightly longer:

I did a fair bit of poking around and my takeaway is that, if you want to re-purpose a disk from one zpool to another, you are best off wiping (at least part of) the disk. Doing a destroy of the previous pool might have worked but I didn't do that (and not clear that I could have since I messed up the grub install so my partitions may have been borked)

The ubuntu instructions did talk about wiping the super-block if you had used the disk in an mdadm raid array... I should have generalized the comment. At any rate, this is a weak answer because I didn't discover a way to cleanly edit the metadata.

Comment: Better than nothing, at least you get to move on from all this.  Here (http://serverfault.com/questions/297029/zfs-on-freebsd-recovery-from-data-corruption) is a discussion related to (BSD) ZFS partition-label meta data that might be of interest.  The crux of their conclusion is: "ZFS maintains 4 labels with partition meta information and the HPA prevents ZFS from seeing the upper two."  Again, congrats on resolving this.

Comment: I tried using `zpool labelclear -f /dev/sda`, but it didn't work, the same error occurred again. Probably the only fool proof way is to zero out the whole disk.